# Unble to insert through web form in wamp, but it works in xampp

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, xampp, wamp

When inserting data through a web form which is running on wamp server, I get database error. I believe it is because the column 'flag' in the "books" table is set to *"null no"* and *"default none"*. Since I do not provide value for *"flag"* column, it gives me this error. See below the error message. However, when I test the same web  form with the same database structure on **xampp** server, it all works fine. The web form is written in PHP CodeIgniter. What is causing this different behavior on xampp and wamp?

```
A Database Error Occurred    
Error Number: 1364
Field 'flag' doesn't have a default value

INSERT INTO `books` (`s_id`, `bookname`, `type`, `status`, `random_string`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES ('1', 'Gone with the wind', 'TX', 'V', '12262006_at4ihw177z_qst', '2006-12-26 22:07:52', '2006-12-26 22:07:52')

Filename: C:\wamp64\www\survey_app\system\database\DB_driver.php
```

My xamp is running on Windows 7 and Wamp on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is not about XAMPP or WAMP. This occurs because, your Table's column definition has a default data. If you are using phpMyAdmin, go to the column in the table, edit the column to set the `DEFAULT` data. If not, in simple query:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `books` CHANGE `flag` `flag` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

Try this query in WAMPServer, where it didn't work. This should fix it.

**phpMyAdmin**

[image: pma]

**Adminer**

[image: adminer]

Comment: @ Praveen but this issue doesn't occur when using xampp. Why is that?

Comment: Likely different MySQL versions and/or configuration. One probably has strict tables enabled.

Comment: Different MySQL Versions, different environment. @Julie Are both the tables are of same `DESC`?

Comment: @ShiraNai7 and Praveen Kumar You must be correct about the version. Xampp is running MariaDB, and Wamp is running MySQL.  I noticed MySQL has stricter rules.

Answer (score 0):

... Set the Row format to DEFAULT